# jQuery use in Titanium Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, mobile, titanium

i have been told that:

> "you can use basically any JS library
>   you want in a WebView. Outside of a
>   WebView, you can use basically any JS
>   library that does not require the DOM
>   (like json2.js, etc.)"

now my deal is that i need to parse an HTML page and some xml responses in the app without displaying the web view or else, now i'm new to jQuery so maybe a won't express well but can i use jQuery's way of parsing the page?? like:

```
$('.my_class').siblings()  etc.
```

thanks

update--

the document to parse are almost always like this:

```
<OPTION value=""> ------- </OPTION>
<OPTION  value="100">AVELLINO</OPTION>
<OPTION  value="112">BENEVENTO</OPTION>
<OPTION  value="71">CASERTA</OPTION>
<OPTION  value="53">NAPOLI</OPTION>
<OPTION  value="90">SALERNO</OPTION>
```

I asked if i can use jQuery's way of parsing because even if i'm not proficient with it I knew it more than Titanium's one, and because there is much more documentation.
By the way reading better the link that you gave me it seems pretty easy maybe i'll go for that one. Thanks

Comment: If you're going to be using jQuery a lot in your app, then i suggest scrap using Appcelerator, and use PhoneGap. It uses HTML5 and CSS3. It also has a load of APIs to access the phones features (like camera, video, audio etc). It's so much better (at this stage).

Comment: i'm asked to use titanium, i can't choose, thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it would more helpful if you provide specific examples of what you are trying to accomplish, for example.. a webpage containing 'blah' structured like 'blah'. There are many a posts in SO about the perils of parsing HTML.

As for parsing XML, I would suggest using the XML parser provided by the framework, not sure why you would introduce an additional framework, jQuery, that you are not familiar with when the Appcelerator Framework already provides the capability.

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Remote+Data